# Architecture for custom rectangular views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, view, 2d

I'm quite new to **Android** and there is a goal I want to achieve but I can't find a proper solution at the moment.

I'm developing in Android and I need an Activity that displays a *two dimensional grid of 2D rectangles* with round corners. The size of the grid gets determined *at runtime* and forwarded from the parent Activity. That means I also have to *create the rectangles at runtime*. As the rectangles also need a custom behaviour I tried the following:

I did write my own class and did inherit from View. In the `onDraw()` method I defined how the rectangle should look like, even though at the beginning I wanted to define the look in a ShapeDrawable XML file and load it in the construction of my custom rectangle. That didn't work well. Now I'm stuck, because when I try to add my view to the layout assined to the activity to display the grid, I get errors. When I set one of those rectangles directly with `setContentView(rectangle)` it gets displayed somewhere in the middle of the screen.

So my questions are:

- Is it the right way to create these rectangles by inheriting from View? (keep in mind that I have to modify the way the are drawn when the user does click on a rectangle and I want to open a menu later when a rectangle gets clicked)
- What's the best way to display these rectangles? Which kind of layout should I use when I wanted display them in a grid-like fashion? The user should later also be able to delete some rectangles. So it must be possible to have *gaps* in the grid.
- As it didn't work to add the rectangles to a layout with this code, how should I do it (I used a LinearLayout)?

  ```
  ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.conf_new_solar_plant_layout);
  SolarPanelView spView = new SolarPanelView(this);
  spView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  layout.addView(spView)
  ```

The error I receive is the following:

```
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartexergy.app/com.smartexergy.app.ConfNewSolarPlantActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.smartexergy.app.ConfNewSolarPlantActivity.onCreate(ConfNewSolarPlantActivity.java:34)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    11-06 11:41:49.862: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Got the error fixed, I forgot to set the layout as the contentView. The rest of the questions still remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued doing some research and in my particular case I did find out that its
the easiest and also a proper way to write my own iew class that extends ImageView. 
In ImageView I did override the onDraw() method to get my custom shape and design.

To display this views in a grid I used a GridLayout and added my custom views 
programatically. In the GridLayout its possible to give each item a x and y coordinate.
About the gaps I'm not quite sure at the moment, but if its not possible I will add
"space" objects to have empty gaps.

Click events are easy to catch in a ImageView, but I think it should be also possible
within the GridLayout, so I can handle the movement and deletion of my rectangles.